# Problem with underscore(_) in Collections.binarySearch (Java)

Tags: java, list, collections, binary-search

Problem:

I am using [Java Tutorials™](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) sourcecode for this. This is the [source code.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextAreaDemoProject/src/components/TextAreaDemo.java)

I tried this:

```
--following with another section of sorted words--
words.add("count");
words.add("cvs");
words.add("dce"); 
words.add("depth");
--following with another section of sorted words--
```

and it works perfectly. However when I use this:

```
--just a section of sorted words--
words.add("count");
words.add("cvs");
words.add("dce_iface"); 
words.add("dce_opnum");
words.add("dce_stub_data");
words.add("depth");
--following with another section of sorted words--
```

It does show `dce_iface` when I type `dce`, but when I type `_` then following with `o` or `s` it shows me something else like `dce_offset` where the offset comes from `words.add("fragoffset");` somewhere in the list.

What can I do to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of these lines in the code:

```
for (w = pos; w >= 0; w--) {
    if (! Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w))) {
        break;
    }
}
```

`_` is not a letter character, so it treats it the same way as a space. You can try changing the condition to:

```
char c = content.charAt(w);
if (! (Character.isLetter(c) || c == '_')) {
```

Comment: OT -- Hmm weird suddenly my Chrome didn't show the textarea for the add comment. Made me puzzled for a while.
@robinst -- Ah I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to add the underscore as "letter" here

```
        // Find where the word starts
        int w;
        for (w = pos; w >= 0; w--) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w))) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with this section in `insertUpdate()`:

```
// Find where the word starts
int w;
for (w = pos; w >= 0; w--) {
    if (! Character.isLetter(content.charAt(w))) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Specifically, `Character.isLetter()` returns false for the underscore character. That means that the word starts after the underscore position.

To solve it, you need to modify the `if` statement to allow any non letter characters you want to use in the words. You could explicitly check for '_' or use `Chacter.isWhiteSpace()` to include all characters that aren't a space, tab or newline.

Comment: @Colin: +1 for detailed explanation.